# Custom Function - Calculate date of first date of next quarter

Tags: date, filemaker

I am trying to create a custom function of given a date in Filemaker, I would like it to determine if this week of fiscal year number is within the first week of quarter else it will calculate the first date next quarter. Our Fiscal year starts on July 1

So for defined requirements our FY starts on July 1 and Qtrs are on week # 1, 14, 27, 40 our weeks go from 1-52 and the week starts on Tuesday (Defined as day 3). If FY starts on Monday than the first week will be from Mon-Tues (Therefore a shortweek) then week 2 will be a full 7 day week.

Example---> If I have a date 09/09/2011 that would be week 11 in Q1, therefore since it is not the first week of the quarter I would like the following date for the next Qtr which would be Wk 14 first date of 9/27/2011. So my evaluation needs to determine whether the given date is within the first week of a qtr (weeks 1, 14, 27, 40) or provide the first week of the next qtr.

Also here is the initial CF I was working with from Brian Dunnings site.

https://www.briandunning.com/cf/147

I know this would be developed in filemaker but there maybe something developed in another language which may apply...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your starting point:

```
Let ( [ 
startFY = Date ( 7 ; 1 ; Year ( Datefield ) - ( Month ( Datefield ) < 7 ) ) ;
firstTuesday = startFY - Mod ( startFY - 2 ; 7 ) ; 
fiscalWeek = Div ( Datefield - firstTuesday ; 7 ) ;  //numbering starts at 0
targetWeek = 13 * Ceiling ( fiscalWeek / 13 ) 
] ;
firstTuesday  + 7 * targetWeek 
)
```

Note that the result is *always* a Tuesday; you may want to adjust this for the boundary cases of fiscal year start and end. The way it works now, you'll get a result of July 30, 2015 for both June 15, 2015 and July 6, 2015.

Comment: - I have a correction . The date of starting FY would be July 1 not July 30.  Also when I use either of the let statement provided, it does not seem to work. As I am provide a date of 4/30/2011 when I input a date of 07/11/2011.  For example when I have a date of 07/11/2011 this week would fall on 2 week of fy there for it will need to calculate to the first week of the next quarter which would be week 14 starting on 09/27/2011. So just to clarify our FY starts on July 1 and the week always start on a Tuesday.  Thanks

Comment: I understand your correction regarding the year - but not what comes afterwards. Please edit your question and explain **exactly** what your requirement is and how your fiscal year is built, including some examples.

Comment: Sure, So for defined requirements our FY starts on July 1 and Qtrs are on week # 1, 14, 27, 40 our weeks go from 1-52. Example---> If I have a date 09/09/2011 that would be week 11 in Q1, therefore since it is not the first week of the quarter I would like the following date for the next Qtr which would be Wk 14 first date of 9/27/2011. So my evaluation needs to determine whether the given date is within the first week of a qtr (weeks 1, 14, 27, 40) or provide the first week of the next qtr.   Thanks

Comment: I further clarified the problem statement. See initial problem statement above.   @michael.hor257k

Comment: @Bigboy6 Yes I have seen that and edited my answer accordingly. All that was 10 days ago.